# Starting new Activity which opens Google Maps

Tags: android, dictionary, android-intent

I'm a beginner in Android. Here I have this code:

```
public class GPS extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View getGPSButton=findViewById(R.id.get_GPS);
        getGPSButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View aboutButton=findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View exitButton=findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
          case R.id.get_GPS:
              Intent i = new Intent (this,getGPS.class);
              startActivity(i);
          case R.id.about_button:
            Intent j = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(j);
            break;
          case R.id.exit_button:
            System.exit(0);
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But getGPS class never starts. Whatever button I press I get About class activity on display.
I know, that my error is in Intent parapeters.What should I write in Intent(...)?
The getGPS function counts longitude&latitude via GPS and then opens Google Maps at that coordinates. Everything is OK in that class.
The exit functions also doesn't work. Both System.exit(0) and finish() do NOT take any effect, it opens About class when I press exit_button.

Waiting for your advices.Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi dear  azizbekian , is there any possibity to be in touch with you. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//you missed the break

```
case R.id.get_GPS:
    Intent i = new Intent (this,getGPS.class);
    startActivity(i);
    break;
```

//if its an button lets do this

```
Button getGPSButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.get_GPS);
        getGPSButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button aboutButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button exitButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Padma, thanks :D Haven't noticed it :)

But now I have another question. Look what I get here: [screenshot](http://goo.gl/5X9qP) Though the getGPS class works fine(I've copied and tested it from other source). Maybe logcat can help you, I can't get accustomed to it yet.

Comment: After pressing "Force Close" the map works pretty well. But what's the  reason this error appears?

Comment: @andranikAzizbekyan its error in your xml file @ line no 15 com.google... plz post error message not screen shot.